# Show Separate product detail page based on attribute value in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, product-attribute, template

Shall we load separate product detail page based on the product attribute value in magento2 ?

I have created the attribute product called "type_of_product"

If this attribute value is "Test 2", I need to load custom template file in product detail page.(**A separate phtml file load all product data**)

If any other value for attribute, Default magento product page should load.

**Note: Once the value of attribute is "Test 2" I don't want to show any other default blocks of product detail page** like image,price,tabs,links, etc..

How this can be implemented in M2.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow Below steps to load separate product detail page based on the product attribute value in magento2

**Step 1** Create event and add below code to `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_controller_product_view">
        <observer name="custom_product_view_layout" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\ProductViewLayout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 2** Create Observer file and Add Below code to `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/ProductViewLayout.php`

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class ProductViewLayout implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($observer->getProduct()->getId());
        $attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('type_of_product')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        if($attributeValue=="Test 2"){
            $page = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            $page->addHandle('catalog_product_custom_layout');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step 3** Create your custom layout to `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_custom_layout.xml`  file and change code as per your requirement on this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.layout.details" template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can call your custom template file using custom 'catalog_product_custom_layout.xml' file

You can change condition `if($attributeValue=="Test 2"){` as per your attribute value in this `ProductViewLayout.php` file

Comment: will it remove all other blocks of detail page if attribute value is "test2"? like image and other blocks in view page?

Comment: It will remove all block and container call on catalog_product_view.xml. Because it will call custom layout 'catalog_product_custom_layout.xml' file and you can manage this custom layout file as per your requirements. Means you will want image block then copy image code from catalog_product_view.xml and paste it in layout 'catalog_product_custom_layout' file and also call your custom template file on custom layout file

Comment: @jafarpinjar Thanks to apply my solution. i am happy to help you

Comment: hi @saneer, in some cases it shows both the page,

Comment: Add another condition to ProductViewLayout.php file and call the second custom layout file on this php file and 'catalog_product_view.xml' and 'custom' layout file merge into the 'secondcustom' layout file

Comment: hi @Saneer, I am seriously not cleared,

Comment: hi @Saneerm, this is still showing me product image.

Comment: 1) Add new condition on this ProductViewLayout.php file. Like : "if($attributeValue=="Test 3"){" 2) Call second custom layout file on this conditions. Like : $page->addHandle('secom_custom_layout'); 3) Create second custom layout file in path : layout/secom_custom_layout.xml. 4) catalog_product_view and catalog_product_custom_layout files should be merge into secom_custom_layout.xml file

Comment: can you please update to answer @saneer,

Comment: if attribute value is "Test 2", I don't need any block to load in detail page except my custom template

Comment: if you will not required media block then remove media block in your catalog_product_custom_layout.xml file as per this <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" remove="true" /> code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88950/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-saneer-ladani).

Comment: hello @Sameer, One issue with this functionality, can't see the products in recently viewed collections, can you please have a look into it?

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar , Please remove or comment this <referenceContainer name="content.aside" remove="true" /> Line from this catalog_product_custom_layout.xml file

Comment: hi @Saneer,still same issue, tab is shown but products are not displayed inside the tab, you can please check here, posted new issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328376/recently-viewed-products-are-empty-in-custom-layout-template-in-magento2

Answer (score 0):

Hope all is well.  I know your origional post is quite old but there does not seems much else available to achieve this.

In Magento 2.3.7 this is the error recieved

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on bool

in your ProductViewLayout around line 18   - would you be able to provide a solution for this - please