# Recently viewed products are empty in custom layout template in Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, product-attribute, recently-viewed

I am loading a new template for product detail page based on the product attribute value.

I have used the following code

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="catalog_controller_product_view">
       <observer name="custom_product_view_layout" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductViewLayout" />
   </event>
</config>
```

Then inside Observer file

**Vendor/Module/Observer/ProductViewLayout.php**

```
class ProductViewLayout implements ObserverInterface
{
 protected $_resultPageFactory;
 protected $product;

 public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 ) {
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->product = $product;
}
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
    $_product = $this->product->load($observer->getProduct()->getId()); 
    $attributeCode = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('is_custom');
    if($attributeCode){
        $attributeValue = $attributeCode->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);       
        if(isset($attributeValue) && $attributeValue == 'Yes'){
            $page = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
            $page->addHandle('catalog_product_custom_layout');
        }
         return $this;
      }
    }
 }
```

Then **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_custom_layout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content.aside" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.layout.details" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/custom.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

In my custom theme I have used below code to display recently viewed products in the tabs.

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" cacheable="false" name="product.info.viewed" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Recently Viewed</argument>
            <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
            <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
            <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price</argument>
            <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

So in the new template file we have custom html code to show this page is different than normal magento product page,

Before the footer we can see the product tabs which have **Details** and **Review** also **Recently Viewed** Tabs, once clicked Recently Viewed tab, the recently viewed products are not appearing.

This may be because we are not viewed the product page, so the recently viewed collection is empty.

Can anyone help me with this issue please!!

Comment: Default Magento 2 PDP showing Related and Upsell product sections. Are you calling this Recent view product section with Widget or code?. Can you please explain?

Comment: @SaneerLadani, yes through code i am calling recently viewed products, in catalog_product_view.xml i have added the code for it

Comment: Can you please explain the Recently view product code in detail or step by step?. I have checked your Question. but there is no any code related to the Recent view product.

Comment: @SaneerLadani, I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: There is an Admin setting that will show the Recently Viewed Products for Not Logged in Customers. Go to Admin => Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Recently Viewed/Compared Products select Yes to (Synchronize widget products with backend storage)

Comment: yes that setting is already configured, the problem is recently viewed products not showing where we are loading custom layout with the attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the below line from this **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_custom_layout.xml** file

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
```

Please try with the Below code to this **catalog_product_view.xml** file

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" cacheable="false" group="detailed_info" name="product.info.recently.viewed" template="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Recently Viewed</argument>
            <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
            <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
            <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price</argument>
            <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment or remove your recent view XML code from ***catalog_product_view.xml*** and Please try with my(above) code and Clear your Magento cache.

Comment: hello @saneer,tried above solution, again same issue, the products which i am loading separate layout are not listing in recently viewed items

Comment: hi @saneer, The product which we are loading separate layout based on attribute is not showing in recently viewed tabs.

Comment: hello @saneer, have you cleared with it?